# Limit Tensorflow GPU memory usage via environmental variable

Tags: linux, tensorflow

I am using a C++ library that internally uses Tensorflow, so I do not have access to session parameters.

When Tensorflow session is created one can limit GPU memory usage by setting `per_process_gpu_memory_fraction` value and `allow growth` flag (example in Python):

```
memory_config = tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.3))
memory_config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True
```

It is also possible to set global value for `allow growth` using environmental variable that will be used if this option is not specified in the `tf.ConfigProto`: `export TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH=true` in linux shell.

I wonder if there's an environmental variable for setting `per_process_gpu_memory_fraction` globally?